# A complex integration formula

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm trying to integrate a formula but I can’t figure it out. Its calculation involves an error function. Here's the formula:

$f(a, b, c)=\int_{0}^{+\pi} d \theta \exp (a \cos \theta) \operatorname{erf}(b \cos \theta+c)$

where, a, b, c presents constant respectively, and $\operatorname{erf}$ presents the error function integral. The exact expression of $\operatorname{erf}$ is
$\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-\eta^{2}} d \eta$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you know the result contains a Bessel function, that seems to imply you've already done some computations that you're not telling us about - how about elaborating? And why are you saying $f$ depends on $\theta $?

Comment: I’m really sorry that I’ve made a mistake that is very obvious. Its calculation doesn’t involve Bessel function directly instead of error function. Only on the condition that b equals 0 and c equals 0, its calculation would involve Bessel function. What’s more, the correct formula will be:  $f(a, b, c)=\int_{0}^{+\pi} d \theta \exp (a \cos \theta) e r f(b \cos \theta+c)$ I’ve modified the question and thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: Also may be written as $$f(a,b,c) = \int_{-1}^1\frac{e^{ax}\mathrm{erf}(bx+c)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;dx$$